# Laravel how to remove url query params?

Tags: laravel

I request api to check user , and the backurl will add  a query param  **token** like this :

```
www.test.com?store_id=2&token = 123
```

I want to show this

```
 www.test.com?store_id=2
```

I handle it in middleware , I wish there is a mothod to remove **token**  before `return $next($request)`
but I didn't find the method. And I can't just use some method to delte this params and redirect , it will make a redirect loop. 
if there is no better method, maybe I will create a new method in LoginController to remove token and redirect to where the page I from.

Comment: How/where is the callback URL created? Can you show us the code behind it?

Comment: `www.test.com?store_id=2` This is not a valid url but this one is `www.test.com/?store_id=2`

Comment: @SagarV You are incorrect. They are both valid. There is no need for the `/` character after the top-level domain.

Answer (score 12):

You can have some sort of global middleware:

```
class  RedirectIfTokenInRequest {
      public function handle($request,$next) {
             if ($request->token) {
                return redirect()->to(url()->current().'?'.http_build_query($request->except("token")));
             }
             return $next($request);
      } 
}
```

This will just redirect if there's a token parameter there. If you need to store it somehow you can use `session(["token" => $request->token]);` to store it before your redirect.

Comment: I had to use http_build_query, but otherwise, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @sehummel yes that's what I meant, I must have confused the function names (updated)

Answer (score 5):

**Laravel 7**

You can remove parameter(s) from url by passing null to `fullUrlWithQuery` function like below:

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['token ' => null])
```

Comment: Works in Laravel 6

Answer (score 4):

Middleware is the best option. You can attach middleware class, to routes, in web or to single method. My middleware proposal:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ClearFromAttributes
{
    /**
     * Remove some attributes which makes some confusion.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('unwanted_param')) {
            return $this->removeFromQueryAndRedirect($request, 'unwanted_param');
        }

        if ($request->has('second_unwanted')) {
            return $this->removeFromQueryAndRedirect($request, 'second_unwanted');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Remove and make redirection.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string                    $parameter
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function removeFromQueryAndRedirect($request, string $parameter)
    {
        $request->query->remove($parameter);
        return redirect()->to($request->fullUrlWithQuery([]));
    }
}
```

Of course, I have more complicated conditions in the `handle` method, in reality.

Usage in controller constructor without touching Kernel file:

```
$this->middleware(ClearFromAttributes::class)->only('index');
```

This is a nice option, for single usage.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 8 added [fullUrlWithoutQuery($keys)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38482)

```
class RemoveParameterFromRequest
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->has('unwanted_parameter')) {
            return redirect()->to($request->fullUrlWithoutQuery('unwanted_parameter'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```